# Adding tmap_icon to legend in r

Tags: r, legend, icon, tmap

The `tmap_icons()` function within the `tmap` package allows users to call a png file into tmap to be used on a map. However, I can't seem to find out how to add custom symbols to the tmap legend. See the reprex below showing the issue:

```r
library(tmap)
#> Warning: package 'tmap' was built under R version 3.6.3
library(sf)
#> Warning: package 'sf' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Linking to GEOS 3.8.0, GDAL 3.0.4, PROJ 6.3.1
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'tidyverse' was built under R version 3.6.2
#> Warning: package 'tidyr' was built under R version 3.6.2


tdir=tempdir()
Stateshpurl= "https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2018/shp/cb_2018_us_state_5m.zip"
if(file.exists(paste(tdir,"/cb_2018_us_county_5m/cb_2018_us_county_5m.shp",sep=""))==FALSE){
 download.file(Stateshpurl, destfile = file.path(tdir,"State_Boundaries.zip"))
 unzip(file.path(tdir,"State_Boundaries.zip"),exdir = tdir)}
US_states=read_sf(paste(tdir,"/cb_2018_us_state_5m.shp",sep=""))

US_states = st_transform(US_states, 5070) 

L48 = US_states %>%
 filter(STATEFP != "02") %>%
 filter(STATEFP != "15") %>%
 filter(STATEFP != "60") %>%
 filter(STATEFP != "64") %>%
 filter(STATEFP != "66") %>%
 filter(STATEFP != "68") %>%
 filter(STATEFP != "69") %>%
 filter(STATEFP != "70") %>%
 filter(STATEFP != "72") %>%
 filter(STATEFP != "74") %>%
 filter(STATEFP != "78")

icon_url="http://29.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m0q2g8mhGK1qk6uvyo1_500.png"
download.file(icon_url, destfile = file.path(tdir,"Image.png"),mode = 'wb')


Icon=tmap_icons(file=paste(tdir,"/Image.png",sep=""))

tm_shape(L48)+
 tm_borders()+
tm_symbols(shape=Icon)
```

[image]

```r
tm_shape(L48)+
  tm_borders()+
  tm_symbols(shape=Icon)+
  tm_add_legend(type="symbol",shape = Icon)
#> Error in shapes[i] - 999: non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Perhaps I am going about this wrong, but it seems like there should be a way to add one of the custom symbols created with `tm_icons()` into the legend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to add a new column with a legend label:

```
# add new variable
L48$icon = "my label"

# create a map
tm_shape(L48)+
  tm_borders()+
  tm_symbols(shape = "icon", shapes = Icon,
             title.shape = "My icon")
```

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: How do you go about adjusting the symbol size within the legend? It defaults very small.